# Full text search on multiple fields in different tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, full-text-search

I want to create a full text search using MsSql 2005.

Here is the structure of my table:

- User-contains fields of `Id`, `fname`, `lname`, `email`, `alternativeemail`
- Attachment-contains fields of `id`, `name`, `category`, `filenameorurl`
- Certification-contains of fileds of `id`, `title`, `school`, `sdate`, `edate`
- EducationalBackground-contain of fields of `id`, `qualification`, `sdate`, `edate`, `school`, `fieldofstudy`
- EmploymentDetails-contain of fields `position`, `positionlevelid`, `specializationid`, `description`

The relationship of user to the other table is a one-to-many relationship.

How can I create an effective query to have quick full text search and return the values of the different tables?

Comment: oh no! i'm so sorry, thanks for the link at least I know how to vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Understanding Full Text Search in SQL Server 2005](http://aspalliance.com/1512_understanding_full_text_search_in_sql_server_2005)
- [SQL Server 2005 Full-Text Search Indexing](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/SQL-Server-Full-Text-Search-Indexing.aspx)
- [Using SQL Server 2005 fulltext search from ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-sql-server-2005-fulltext-search-from-aspnet-20)
- [Additional help](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-sql-server-2005-fulltext-search-from-aspnet-20)